# How Eclipse check available plugin in some environment?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I made some Eclipse plugin and update site on Indigo(Eclipse v3.7).

I can debug my plugin with new Eclipse instance, but I can't install my plugin via update site.

When I try to test install my plugin with Indigo (same environment as dev environment), the install wizard says:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
com.mytest.helloworld.feature.group [1.0.0.201203071543] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.
```

(I tried to install my plugin with the same version of eclipse - Indigo.
And, My plugin works fine after manual install.)

Is there any check point to solve this?

How eclipse check available plugin? (based on what information?)

Here is my features.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
  id="com.mytest.helloworld"
  label="mytest Feature"
  version="1.0.0.qualifier"
  provider-name="mytest.com"
  plugin="com.mytest.helloworld"
  os="aix,hpux,linux,macosx,qnx,solaris,win32"
  ws="carbon,cocoa,gtk,motif,photon,win32,wpf"
  nl="en,ko"
  arch="ia64,ia64_32,PA_RISC,ppc,sparc,x86,x86_64">
   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      [Enter Feature Description here.]
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      [Enter License Description here.]
   </license>

   <url>
      <update label="mytest update" url="http://localhost:8088/plugin"/>
   </url>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.expressions" version="3.4.101"     match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" version="0.9.5" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.jdom" version="1.1.1" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.apache.commons.httpclient" version="3.1.0" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core" version="3.5.2" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.5.2"     match="greaterOrEqual"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="com.mytest.helloworld"
         os="aix,hpux,linux,macosx,qnx,solaris,win32"
         ws="carbon,cocoa,gtk,motif,photon,win32,wpf"
         nl="en,ko"
         arch="ia64,ia64_32,PA_RISC,ppc,sparc,x86,x86_64"
         download-size="1000"
         install-size="1000"
         version="0.0.0"
         unpack="false"/>

   <plugin
         id="com.mytest.helloworld.nl1"
         os="aix,hpux,linux,macosx,qnx,solaris,win32"
         ws="carbon,cocoa,gtk,motif,photon,win32,wpf"
         nl="en,ko"
         arch="ia64,ia64_32,PA_RISC,ppc,sparc,x86,x86_64"
         download-size="1"
         install-size="1"
         version="0.0.0"
         fragment="true"
         unpack="false"/>
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you been able to run the plugin in a new Eclipse instance from your development environment? I.e press the run button and start a new Eclipse application with your plugin active.
2. It seems like there is some issue with filters, either you have defined a version requirement that doesnt work, or perhaps defined an OS that doesnt work. Posting your feature.xml might help.

Edit based on comment:

Try to remove the OS specific parts from the XML, i.e the properties "os", "ws", "arch" and perhaps "nl".

You would get

```
<feature
  id="com.mytest.helloworld"
  label="mytest Feature"
  version="1.0.0.qualifier"
  provider-name="mytest.com"
  plugin="com.mytest.helloworld">
```

You only need to enter those properties if you are restricting the choice in some way, that is, your plugin contains OS specific code that will only work on some operating systems/architectures.

Comment: Thank you Fredrik. I Add what you said to original post. I tried to install my plugin without "requires" part in features.xml, But it didn't help. :(

Comment: @kizmo Editer answer based on your comment